# Dynamically add filter to SQLAlchemy TextClause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Assume I have a SQLAlchemy table which looks like:

```
class Country:
    name = VARCHAR
    population = INTEGER
    continent = VARCHAR
    num_states = INTEGER
```

My application allow seeing name and population for all Countries. So I have a [`TextClause`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause) which looks like

```
"select name, population from Country"
```

I allow raw queries in my application so I don't have option to change this to selectable.

At runtime, I want to allow my users to choose a field name and put a field value on which I want to allow filtering. eg: User can say I only want to see name and population for countries where Continent is Asia. So I dynamically want to add the filter

```
.where(Country.c.continent == 'Asia')
```

But I can't add `.where` to a `TextClause`.

Similarly, my user may choose to see name and population for countries where num_states is greater than 10. So I dynamically want to add the filter

```
.where(Country.c.num_states > 10)
```

But again I can't add `.where` to a `TextClause`.

What are the options I have to solve this problem?

Could subquery help here in any way?

Comment: What are you constrained by? Can you modify the `TextClause`? Do you know the structure of the `TextClause`?

Comment: I cannot modify the TextClause. I don't know the structure of TextClause. The program only tells the user the name of Table. After that user enters the TextClause, also user defines the other column(eg: num_states) and value(eg: less than 10) that needs to be combined with TextClause.

Answer (score 4):

Please add a filter based on the conditions. filter is used for adding where conditions in sqlalchemy.

```
Country.query.filter(Country.num_states > 10).all()
```

You can also do this:

```
query = Country.query.filter(Country.continent == 'Asia')
if user_input == 'states':
    query = query.filter(Country.num_states > 10)
query = query.all()
```

Comment: Where are you using TextClause here?

Answer (score 1):

This is not doable in a general sense without parsing the query. In relational algebra terms, the user applies projection and selection operations to a table, and you want to apply selection operations to it. Since the user can apply arbitrary projections (e.g. user supplies `SELECT id FROM table`), you are not guaranteed to be able to always apply your filters on top, so you have to apply your filters *before* the user does. That means you need to rewrite it to `SELECT id FROM (some subquery)`, which requires parsing the user's query.

**However**, we can sort of cheat depending on the database that you are using, by having the database engine do the parsing for you. The way to do this is with CTEs, by basically shadowing the table name with a CTE.

Using your example, it looks like the following. User supplies query

```
SELECT name, population FROM country;
```

You shadow `country` with a CTE:

```
WITH country AS (
  SELECT * FROM country
  WHERE continent = 'Asia'
) SELECT name, population FROM country;
```

Unfortunately, because of the way SQLAlchemy's CTE support works, it is tough to get it to generate a CTE for a `TextClause`. The solution is to basically generate the string yourself, using a custom compilation extension, something like this:

```
class WrappedQuery(Executable, ClauseElement):
    def __init__(self, name, outer, inner):
        self.name = name
        self.outer = outer
        self.inner = inner

@compiles(WrappedQuery)
def compile_wrapped_query(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    return "WITH {} AS ({}) {}".format(
        element.name,
        compiler.process(element.outer),
        compiler.process(element.inner))

c = Country.__table__
cte = select(["*"]).select_from(c).where(c.c.continent == "Asia")
query = WrappedQuery("country", cte, text("SELECT name, population FROM country"))
session.execute(query)
```

From my tests, this only works in PostgreSQL. SQLite and SQL Server both treat it as recursive instead of shadowing, and MySQL does not support CTEs.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything nice for this in the documentation for this. I ended up resorting to pretty much just string processing.... but at least it works!

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

query = """select name, population from Country"""

if continent is not None:
    additional_clause = """WHERE continent = {continent};"""
    query = query + additional_clause
    text_clause = text(
        query.format(
            continent=continent,
        ),
    )
else:
     text_clause = text(query)

with sql_connection() as conn:
    results = conn.execute(text_clause)
```

You could also chain this logic with more clauses, although you'll have to create a boolean flag for the first WHERE clause and then use AND for the subsequent ones.